# Не удается закомитить изменения в коде

Tags: android-studio, git, контроль-версий

Использую Android Studio.
Возникла интересная проблема, при попытке закомить мне отвечают:

```
Error:On branch developer
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/developer' by 3 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
 during executing git commit --only -F /private/var/folders/pv/09z3rgn95wd1wt7l8vynhg880000gn/T/git-commit-msg-7615666565705146184.txt -- RabCreen/src/test/java/com/my/package/name/Base.java
```

или

```
Error:On branch developer
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/developer'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
 during executing git commit --only -F /private/var/folders/pv/09z3rgn95wd1wt7l8vynhg880000gn/T/git-commit-msg-6003046563135798165.txt -- RabCreen/src/test/java/com/my/package/name/Base.java
```

Разницу я вижу, если что. Изначально там были сообщения о том, что у меня есть unversioned файлы, но я их добавил либо в git, либо в gitignore.

Гугление ничего не дало.    
Подскажите как быть?  Про крайние меры как удалить репу и слить заново я знаю. На данном этапе хочется понять в чем проблема и как её решить.

**UPD:**  Эта проблема возникает абсолютно на любом файле.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что изменениями были только пробелы. Комит был тестовый для проверки билд сервера.